# How to pass value on enter?

Tags: angularjs

I have directive:

```
angular.module("mainModule").directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

I have input field :

```
 <input type="search" ng-model="searchText" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" placeholder="@Translator.Translate("SEARCH_OFFER")" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" ng-change="search()" ng-enter="Search(searchText)">
```

Problem is when i hit enter i cant pass value `searchText` to controller its undefined...any suggestion?

EDIT:Its not debaunce because when i remove it i get same result.Any other suggestion?

Comment: What value are you trying to pass?

Comment: what ever user enter

Comment: @pravee-n any suggestion? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.getVal = function(event) {
  var commentEl = angular.element(event.target);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   alert(commentEl.val());
  }

 };
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <section ng-controller="homeCtrl">
        <input ng-keydown="getVal($event)">
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
```

I expect that you are waiting a second before the scope value changes.

Comment: when i wait even for 5seconds i get $scope.searchText undefined